# Is it realistic for me to expect that I might be able to use Scala for a full stack?

Tags: scala, playframework

I am thinking of writing a web app in Scala using the Play! framework for the front end, and probably MongoDB for the backend. Is there any reason why I wouldn't be able to / want to use scala for the entire application? In other words, are there areas where I would be forced to use ruby or php? I like the idea of just having the full stack in Scala, but I don't really know if that is realistic or not.

I am very new to web development, but have experience in java, which is why play framework and scala seem like good choices. But I apologize if my questions doesn't exactly make sense.

Comment: Suggest try programmers.stackexchange.com for this one.

Comment: I thought stack overflow was for programmers?

Comment: SO is for questions and answers to real answerable objective questions. P.SE is for subjective "should I do x", or "what do you think about y"?

Comment: The only reason I may thought of is that ruby and php has lower entry-level. There was a recent buzz about *scala is too complex for average developer*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You bring up a good question re: Scala for full stack web devel.

I would say, generally, yes, you can do it all in Scala (and compile-time checked code to boot) with one exception*, the template engine layer

Play provides their own template engine, but don't expect to get code completion in your IDE; technically it's strongly typed, but your IDE won't pick up Scala code; it will be interpreted as plain text in the IDE.  Loading in browser window reveals error(s) and applicable line number(s) so you do avoid runtime problems of ruby, python, php, etc. frameworks.

Same deal with Scalatra and the Scalate template engine. You won't get that rapid-fire feedback of compiler checked/completed code that you do get when writing straight .scala file code in your IDE.

Now, if you're an EMACS, VIM, etc. user, no great loss, but then again, having auto completed code at both scala and template engine layers is hard to beat. Apparently IntelliJ is providing a plugin this summer that will at long last provide syntax highlighting, code completion, etc. for Scalate, an amazing project that is over 3 years old and still has zero IDE support ;-(

- Lift's approach is of course entirely different and somewhat gets around this weak spot in existing Scala tools, but then again, you lose xhtml tag completion!

Currently with the Eclipse Aptana plugin I use .erb support to hammer out code completed xhtml and then sbt plugins for LESS and CoffeeScript. You can make it work, just a bit of a hassle in current state of Scala IDEs.

Please correct me if I am wrong on any of this, would love to hear otherwise. As of a month ago, the below held true in my devel environment (Scala IDE 2.0)

Comment: I don't think that missing code completion will the show-stopper here. I think the question was more targeted at possible technical restrictions, but of course I can't be sure :)

Comment: @NiklasB. yes quite true, but it is important to note that tool support goes hand-in-hand with a so called full stack. In other words, Scala adoption would be quite small if one were forced to go "blind" in vi or notepad.  This is just pointing out that things are quite rosy in Scala right now (Scala IDE 2.0 is, imo, awesome) with the exception of template engine support. Look over at M$ stack and there you have tool support from code-to-template-to-(java)script built into Visual Studio. It's not the only reason, but C# is Stackoverflow's #1 language at least in part due to tooling.

Comment: As one of the VIM hackers, I just wanted to mention that the language and a good text editor in general is much more important than a particular IDE or "intellingent" code assistance. In my opinion, Scala is definitely a more productive language than for example Java, regardless of the development environment.

Comment: take away the M in VIM and tell me if you'd feel the same way ;-) Obviously I am not part of the text editor population, quite ignorant to that world in fact. Are you able to get Scala syntax highlighting and compile time checking in VIM?? I assume so, but just find it hard to believe that a text editor can hang with an IDE when it comes to scala + xhtml + css + javascript. I believe the mighty O himself has left EMACS for Scala IDE...

Comment: VI of course is a 30-year old, unmaintained piece of software. VIM as a modern alternative is vastly more useful. Syntax highlighting for any type of language (or mixture of language) comes by default or can be easily installed using plugins. Type checking can be set up with a bit of effort. But this is not where general-purpose text editors have an advantage over full-blown IDE stacks. It's the [raw text editing](http://www.viemu.com/a-why-vi-vim.html) that makes them so powerful. VIM and EMACS also glance at interacting with version control and for general file management.

Comment: The important thing is: If you know a language, *you don't need intelligent code assistance*. In fact, it's typically more annoying than helpful. But I won't start a discussion about IDE's vs. text editors here. But that one is a sure thing: Once you have realized how vastly faster you can work if you don't need to use your mouse, there's no way any IDE can satisfy you as a development environment any more.

Comment: +1 for that link, love that, "The VI Gang Sign" ;-) I've used VI (poorly) for years, just quick and dirty ssh editing tasks, and actually downloaded VIM a couple of weeks ago, but have yet to dive in.

Comment: In Scala I spend far less time editing than in Java. The most important functin in IDEA I am using is looking up types of expressions, looking up expected parameter types and adding type annotations to expressions.

Answer (score 4):

To make it short: I don't see any reason why you should use PHP or Ruby. You can do it completely in Java (Play1.x) or Scala. If you prefer Scala I would recommend Playframework 2.0.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend hanging on for 2.0 if you can wait, because it's much better.